# Equation numbering restart for every theorem

Tags: equations, numbering, theorems

How to make the equation numbering restart after every proof? One alternative is to use

```
\numberwithin{equation}{theorem}
```

but it shows the chapter and theorem number, like (5.5.1). I want the numbering to exclude the chapter and theorem number, so it only shows (1) instead of (5.5.1).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add

```
\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{equation}}
```

To get rid of the prefix.